# Can't upload file with Multer, React Native and Axios

Tags: node.js, react-native, axios, multipartform-data, multer-s3

I know there are thousands of questions like this, but none of the solutions works for me:

1. Change to Fetch Api
2. Use format {uri: ..., type: ..., name: ...} in formData

I also have noticed that I can't send the formData directly in the "data" axios's property (when using Axios({...})), because the formData object has a property call "._parts", so I have to do:

```
let formData = new FormData()
formData('image', {uri: imagePicker.uri, name: 'some_name.jpeg', type: 'image/jpeg'})
formData('data', {name: 'Andrea'})

let xmlHttp = await Axios({
               method: 'POST',
               url: `url...`,
               data: formData._parts,
               headers: {
                 Authorization: `Bearer ${_token}`,
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
               },
              } ).catch(error => {
                  throw error
              });
```

Then, in Node, I get this:

```
 req.body    -> [Object: null prototype] {}
 req.file    ->  undefined
```

upload.single("image"), in router.post and multerS3.

Some idea? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with Axios for 6 days :D , there is no problem with Multer i got. 
but in the code you leave `data` should be `formData` not the `formData._parts`. 
just check it if it doesnt solve your problem i strongly recommend you to use https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob ,because the Axios package has got some issues you can also check it from github issue.
for me Using the `RNFetchBlob` did the job i hope it helped

Comment: I will try in the morning jeje and do you know why I get  "_parts" property in the formData? I can't explain why jaja

Comment: jajajaja i dont know why you used it ! and i dont have any idea! :D man that works , morning you will be highhhhhhh :D Gnight